# How to convert .apk file to .exe?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

I have created one App in Eclipse. I want to convert that App to .exe file [ means .apk file to  .exe file ] ...

or

I want that App should run by downloading and clicking on it . It should run without the Help of Eclipse or AVD Manager...

If anybody can help me......

Comment: Your Windows(which supports .exe) in NOT Android that it can install APK. So, simple.(**There is no way to do it**).

Comment: Hey thnx... but is there any way to make that app as a install-able file???

Comment: No. Just read my comment. It says it is not possible, up to this time.

Comment: Please Go on to delete such Silly Questions So that you can get back your Reputation that are lost due to -ve Voting.

Comment: If you're a programmer, you have to create it again manually as EXE using whatever programming language software you have such as Java or VB. If you're not, why don't you just Google it for a file converter that converts APK to EXE? Haiz...This question community only serves to help what codes or bugs you wanna know and fix, not asking for file converter.

Answer (score 4):

You can't create .exe file of Android application.

> I want that App should run by downloading and clicking on it . The
>   should run without the Help of Eclipse or AVD Manager...

Your .apk (Android application) runs only Android Environment. And you can achieve it by just click on apk file if it install on your android supported device.

Now some other OS manufacture support android .apk file to run on their environment. But this need some basic conversion process to support that environment.